# Java this passing as argument to a method

Tags: java

Please read the point 4 of the following tutorial (Usage of This keyword)

http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword

How can `this` be a formal argument of a method.

In case of constructor, if constructor is like - Const(OBJECT obj), we can pass `this`, just to invoke the constructor..

What can be possible scenarios where passing `this` as actual argument in method will come in handy?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to pass this to a ctor when it already has it built in.  MAKES NO SENSE.  Voting down, voting to close.

Comment: You are not passing this, you are calling this() to make a call to default constructor.

Comment: Please read the point 4 of following tutorial before closing the question   http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword

Comment: You didn't read the tutorial very well. `this()` can be called in _constructors_, not _methods_.

Comment: its written - this can be passed as an argument to method call.. Please check point 4

Comment: No, you didn't read well: point 4 talks about **`this`**, not **`this()`**. Those are two VERY different things.

Comment: I provided an example to illustrate the use.

Comment: After reading the tutorial I too do not understand why one would pass this to a method.  Too bad this question was aggressively closed.

Comment: Not to mention that there are 3 decent answers to this allegedly non-question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call this from constructor to give a call to other constructors(based on the call eg this() : you are calling default constructor, this(param) you are calling paramitarized constructor. Now this as a parameter, bottom line is, **this refers to current object**, so any place where in you want to pass current object as a parameter to any method, pass this. I hope this helps. If you read the tutorial properly, you can actually understand.

Comment: yeah i was wrong.. its this not this().. but can i have some example where we need to pass this as method argument?

Comment: @user2093576 in method arguments, not much use; in constructor arguments to other classes, there are uses, yes, including listeners and builders

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are confusing `this()` with `this`.

The first one is used to invoke the constrcutor. For eaxmple you could provide a default constructor which initializes the object. Then you provide additional constructors with spezialized functionality. Instead of rewriting the initialization you could either provide something like an `initialize()` function or invoke a particular contstructor (in this case the default).

Example where different constructors are invoked:

```
 public class TestClass
 {
      private int x;
      private String s;

      public TestClass()
      {
          x = 0;
          s = "defaultvalue";
      }

      public TestClass(int iv)
      {
          this();    <-- Default constructor invoked
          x = iv;
          s = "defaultvalue1";
      }

      public TestClass(int iv, String sv)
      {
          this(iv);   <-- int Constructor invoked, which in turn invokes the default constructor
          s = sv;
      }
 }
```

The second is simply a reference to the current object. this is very usefull if you have a main class which implements some interfaces, and then passes itself to other classes which make use of these interfaces.

Example pseudocode to illustrate how this can be used:

```
class MyWindow
    extends JPanel
{
    private JButton mButton = new JButton("Sample");
    ....

    public void addButtonPressedListener(ActionListener oListener)
    {
        mButton.addActionListener(oListener);
    }
}

class Main
  implements ActionListener
{
    public Main()
    {
        MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
        w.addButtonPressedListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oEvent)
    {
        // Whenever the user presses that particular button in my mainwindow
        // we get notified about it here and can do something about it.
        System.out.println("Button in the GUI has been pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this`, as others have pointed already, refers to the *current object* and is used to pass a *reference to itself*. I just want to illustrate an example to hopefully clear this for you. One of the scenarios where you would typically do this is *event processing or notifications*.

Suppose, you have an `EntityManager` and you want to fire an `UpdateEvent` any time an `Entity` is added or deleted. You could have the following in your add/remove methods.

```
public class EntityManager implements ApplicationEventPublisher {

    Set<Entity> entities = new HashSet<Entity>();

    public void addEntity (Entity e) {
        entities.add (e);
        publishEvent (new UpdateEvent (this, UpdateType.ADD, e));
    }

    public void removeEntity (Entity e) {
      if (entities.contains (e)) {
        entities.remove (e);
        publishEvent (new UpdateEvent (this, UpdateType.REMOVE, e));
      }
    }

    protected void publishEvent (Event e) {
      // handles the nitty-gritty of processing events
    }
}
```

where `this` refers to the event source which is the object itself.

So, the `EntityManager` was passed as part of the `Event` so that the notification recipient could later on access it by, say, an `Event.getSource()` method call.